# Weird functionality when configuring font using tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Hello guys here is a most simplified code which I could achieve for example purpose.

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font

win = tk.Tk()

mainFont = tk.font.Font(family="Courier", size=10, weight="normal", slant="roman")

def font_change():
    newFont = mainFont
    newFont.configure(weight="bold")
    myText.tag_add("bold_", "sel.first", "sel.last")
    myText.tag_configure("bold_", font=newFont)

myText = tk.Text(win, font=mainFont)
myButton = tk.Button(win, text="Button", command=font_change)

myText.pack()
myButton.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

This should be pretty straight forward, but it just doesn't work.
I just want to change font of selection this way,
what it does, it changing font of all text in text widget.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I know I could sort this problem this way for example:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font

win = tk.Tk()

mainFont = tk.font.Font(family="Courier", size=10, weight="normal", slant="roman")
newFont = tk.font.Font(family="Courier", size=10, weight="normal", slant="roman")

def font_change():
    newFont.configure(weight="bold")
    myText.tag_add("bold_", "sel.first", "sel.last")
    myText.tag_configure("bold_", font=newFont)

myText = tk.Text(win, font=mainFont, height=3, width=10)
myButton = tk.Button(win, text="Button", command=font_change)

myText.pack()
myButton.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

and it's working

From my investigation through python IDLE:

```
>>> mainFont = tk.font.Font(family="Courier", size=10, weight="normal", slant="roman")
>>> mainFont
<tkinter.font.Font object at 0xb59a768c>
>>> newFont = mainFont
>>> mainFont
<tkinter.font.Font object at 0xb59a768c>
>>> newFont
<tkinter.font.Font object at 0xb59a768c>
>>> otherFont = tk.font.Font(family="Courier", size=10, weight="normal", slant="roman")
>>> otherFont
<tkinter.font.Font object at 0xb59a762c>
```

so basically when you try assign font to new name, python place it in the same cell of memory what screw up what I try to achieve. Why it does that and how to sort this to save a code. Thanks.

Comment: As you said, reference assignment is used for non-primitive type variable.  For your case, you can use `newFont = mainFont.copy()`.

Comment: You're using `mainFont` in the text widget as the default font, so when you change `mainFont` it's going to change any widget that uses that font. That's one of the main features of using fonts as objects.

Comment: Thanks guys. newFont = mainFont.copy() works fine.